# Magento 1.6 - Paypal Standard is not taking to paypal Payment page

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, magento-1.6

My `Magento 1.6` settings with `paypal` is not working at all. I am trying to setup `Website Payments Standard` however its not working. Its taking me to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home instead of the Payment page (similar is the issue without sandbox, i.e. with live).

here is what is already done:

1. I have setup the **developer's account** at the new https://developer.paypal.com
2. created **sellers and buyers test accounts** there
3. setup seller's needed basic info at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ (such as Page Style and IPN)..
4. enabled mage_paypal at **magento admin**
5. enabled 'Website Payments Standard' at Paypal section at magento admin and setup all the relevant settings as needed.

Now, I can see the paypal payment option at the **checkout page (onepage)**, but when I click on "**Place order**" at Order Review section, it takes me to the black page and says that its redirecting me to paypal... then it takes me to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home instead of payment page.

I think this is due to new changes in Paypal system and also due to the magento system because we have used paypal standard so many times on regular custom websites but never seen this....

---

**[UPDATES]**
Here is the form on the redirect page:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr" id="paypal_standard_checkout" 
name="paypal_standard_checkout" method="POST">
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="**********" />
</form>
```

As you can see, it not the regular form of paypal we are used to.... So either its an issue with magento, or maybe its suppose to be like this....

---

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: The form provided isn't complete. It's missing a lot of variables that actually define the item details or at least the "cmd" and "hosted_button_id" values. 
That would cause a problem like this. If you don't provide the actual item details or the "cmd" value it will drop you off on the PayPal home page.

Comment: I couldnt solve this issue, so I decided to go with Express checkout.... that worked...

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've managed to solve it!
I have found several questions like this all over the Internet, none of which had answer that worked for me.
In my case the solution was trivial:

I had to go to Admin>System>Configuration and from top-left dropdown menu select configuration scope for particular store. There is additional configuration for paypal hidden here - i found that i had sandbox mode turned on here - that configuration was overwriting settings for whole magento.